# setMargins method is not working on custom ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, viewgroup

I am working on a project where my portion of work is to create a sliding layout on main screen which will partially appear at bottom when the app will start and we can scroll that layout. And then I have to add child views inside of it which will be cards. Now for that I have created a custom `ViewGroup` and I will add them programmatically.

I have succeed in making most of the portion of the task.

I have created a custom `FrameLayout` for sliding layout.

Then I used it and added in XML.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.dhrumil.airhockey.OverflowView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/layer_list"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Now after that I have created a java class named `MyCardView` which exends `ViewGroup`.

```
public class MyCardView extends ViewGroup {

    public MyCardView(Context context){
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr){
        super(context, attrs,defStyleAttr);
        init(context);
    }

    public MyCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(context);
    }

    public void init(Context context){

    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean b, int l, int i1, int i2, int i3) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int count = getChildCount();
        int curWidth, curHeight, curLeft, curTop, maxHeight;

        //get the available size of child view
        int childLeft = this.getPaddingLeft();
        int childTop = this.getPaddingTop();
        int childRight = this.getMeasuredWidth() - this.getPaddingRight();
        int childBottom = this.getMeasuredHeight() - this.getPaddingBottom();
        int childWidth = childRight - childLeft;
        int childHeight = childBottom - childTop;

        maxHeight = 0;
        curLeft = childLeft;
        curTop = childTop;
        //walk through each child, and arrange it from left to right
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                //Get the maximum size of the child
                child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
                curWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                curHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
                //wrap is reach to the end
                if (curLeft + curWidth >= childRight) {
                    curLeft = childLeft;
                    curTop += maxHeight;
                    maxHeight = 0;
                }
                //do the layout
                child.layout(curLeft, curTop, curLeft + curWidth, curTop + curHeight);
                //store the max height
                if (maxHeight < curHeight)
                    maxHeight = curHeight;
                curLeft += curWidth;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then I am trying to add objects of `MyCardView` into custom `FrameLayout` of mine programmatically.

Here is the method inside `onCreate()` which does the task. Which is to add two custom `ViewGroup`s into one `LinearLayout`.

```
public void setupText(){
    FrameLayout frame = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.overflow_frame);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    ViewGroup vg = new MyCardView(getBaseContext());
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,200);
    vg.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    ViewCompat.setElevation(vg, 5);

    TextView tvTemp = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    tvTemp.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tvTemp.setText("Hello There");

    vg.addView(tvTemp);

    ViewGroup vg1 = new MyCardView(getBaseContext());
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams1 = new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,200);
    layoutParams1.setMargins(0,10,0,0);
    vg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    ViewCompat.setElevation(vg1, 5);

    TextView tvTemp1 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    tvTemp1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    tvTemp1.setText("Hello There 2");

    vg1.addView(tvTemp1);

    linearLayout.addView(vg,layoutParams);
    linearLayout.addView(vg1,layoutParams1);

    frame.addView(linearLayout);
}
```

Now what happens is I am trying to set margin of ViewGroup but that doesn't seem to apply. Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake I was doing is, in my code I have declared an instance of `ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams1` and I am passing the same instance in `linearLayout.addView(vg1,layoutParams1)` but the method `addView()` accepts `View` as first argument and an instance of `LayoutParams` as second.

So I think that was the problem (not fully sure). So I changed my code to

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,200);
```