# How to call setMargins(); on a custom ViewGroup in android?

Tags: java, android, layout

I created a custom viewGroup by extending ViewGroup, but even though I can access LayoutParams I can't seem to use the setMargins attribute for that object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setMargins method is not working on custom ViewGroup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317439/setmargins-method-is-not-working-on-custom-viewgroup)

Answer (score 1):

If you can access `LayoutParams` (they are not `null`), try casting them to [`MarginLayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html). Most of the `LayoutParams` (e.g. `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`, `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` extend `MarginLayoutParams`)

```
MarginLayoutParams params = (MarginLayoutParams) getLayoutParams();
params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);
yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Hope it will help!